# Lumen (Laravel) routing not passing route parameter to controller

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing, lumen

I'm having some trouble with Lumen's routing. I'm trying to capture the uri using regex in a route.

When I try to pass the captured data to a controller method, the variable is empty, yet when I do the same using a closure, the variable shows as expected.  Here's the code:

This works:

```
$app->get('{categoryUrlPath:[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+}', function($categoryUrlPath) {
  echo $categoryUrlPath;
});
```

This doesn't work:

```
$app->get('{categoryUrlPath:[a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+}', ['uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\FrontController@showSearch']);
```

and inside the controller:

```
public function showSearch($categoryUrlPath) {
    return $categoryUrlPath;    
}
```

Debugging the controller's showSearch method with

```
print_r(app('request')->route());
```

shows that the variable is there:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Array ( [uses] => App\Http\Controllers\FrontController@showSearch ) [2] => Array ( [categoryUrlPath] => this/is/a/captured/uri ) )
```

But still it isn't passed as $categoryUrlPath

Any help appreciated - I'm puzzled. Also, I realise the are other (easier) ways to capture just the URI but I have a specific reason for doing it this way and, besides, I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong with the router here.

Thanks!

Comment: One thing I notice... the two `$app-get()` expressions are not the same. Specifically, you have a leading `/` on one but not the other. That *might* be the problem (assuming it's not just a typo).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it makes no difference. The result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type hinting on a controller method will make your variable "go empty". Simply don't type hint. Your closure approach doesn't have the type hint, but your controller method does.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but removing the type hint makes no difference on testing. There's still nothing passed.

Comment: Strangely the result was different when I tried again: type-hinting does indeed make the controller variable "go empty".

Comment: I didn't research too much to be honest, but I had the same problem as you did and the fix was exactly the same, I think it definitely has something to do with how the IoC works. However, now we at least know that type hinting kills default values.